# How to connect to a VM on ESXi by command line?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I want to connect to a VM running on an ESXi host by command line.

With VMWare Workstation, I can use this command to start an view a local VM:

```
vmware.exe -X -q <path>\MyVM.vmx
```

With ESXi, I managed to connect to the host:

```
VpxClient.exe -i -s <adress> -u <user> -p <password>
```

But, how can I connect directly to a VM running on that host?

Comment: Not tempted to look at the documentation? we on serverfault expect question askers to have done the basics before coming here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question implies a lack of basic research.

Comment: @Chopper3 I did look at the documentation. As you can see, i found the above parameters already, but could not find the one solving my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vmware vsphere client tool (https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/datacenter_cloud_infrastructure/vmware_vsphere/5_5) to connect to the esxi host. By using that tool, you can see consoles of the VMs which running in it

Comment: I am using vSphere 5.5 allready to connect to the host. What i am looking for is to connect directly to one of these consoles...

Comment: After right click on a VM, you select Open Console

Comment: I know that i can do it manualy. What i mean is, how to do this directly by command line...

Comment: You must assign Ip for each VM. If your VM is using Windows, you can use remote desktop to connect. If your VM is using Linux, you can use ssh to access the VM

Answer (score 0):

to connect on a VM hosted on the ESXi:

vmware.exe /? *will show available command options*

-H HOST (IP or NAME)
-U User
-P Password
Location of VM files ([datastore#])

vmplayer.exe **-H** VMS001 **-U** "root" **-P** "P@55W0RD" "[datastore1] VWS001/VWS001.vmx"

vmware.exe **-H** VMS001 **-U** "root" **-P** "P@55W0RD" "[datastore1] VWS001/VWS001.vmx"

more:
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Automatically-connect-to-remote-VMs-at-program-start/m-p/920917

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-7369457F-FE1D-40FE-97B6-B29CA4916CCD.html